# How to pass task attachments down a workflow chain of tasks in sharepoint designer?

Tags: sharepoint-2007, workflow, task, attachment

I am developing a workflow which involves a chain of tasks. This chain is started atomatically on the creation of a specific list item. The workflow creates a new "readonly" list item in another list to hold all the information and creates a new task item to collect more info. This new task then updates the "readonly" list item with its new data and creates the next task in the chain.

The initial list item can have attachments. How can I transfer or otherwise link these attachments to the new readonly list item ?

I only have sharepoint designer and cant implement this in code due to corporate IT restrictions. (or can I?)

Answer (score 1):

Ok well I have a plan and nobody has even looked at this question yet.

I will edit the NewForm.aspx and include javascript to capture the fileupload fields in a PreSaveAction. Then call updateListItems Web Service with javascript to create items in an Attachments list. Creating these items triggers a workflow that concatentaes the attachment names together with the URL of the attachment directory for the original list. Then all I need to do is grab the Id from the original list item when its created and add that back into the concatenated links to finish them.
Then each task in the chain can pull out the concatenated list of links back to the original attachments.

easy

Lets see how it goes!
Anybody any other ideas?

Comment: Seems you answered your own question. I know this is 11 years old at this point, but this is a very complicated scenario and many would have their eyes gloss over at it. This would certainly work, but they might ask why you are saving things off to update them later, instead of doing it on the fly, at the time of the original upload?